# passing a dynamic class name as a prop in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props, react-css-modules

I am trying to make a modal toggle between visible and invisible by applying an invisible or visible class to the surrounding div of the component. In the App component I am using state to pass the className dynamically like this :

```
 ` <Modal newClass={modalState ? "visible" : "invisible"} /> `
```

and I am trying to apply that style to the Modal component like this:

`<div className={`styles.${props.newClass}`}>`

I am using a module for the css file importing "styles" from "./Modal.module.css" and when I inspect the element on the web browser the class name comes out as "styles.invisible" or "styles.visible" instead of the dynamic name the module is supposed to create. Is there a better way to do this or is there a way to fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to just pass visible/invisible as prop and according to this prop choose style from module:

```
<Modal visible={true} />
```

```
const Modal = ({visible})=>{

return <div className={visible ? styles.visible : styles.invisible} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method would be to use a ternary operator in the className to get the required class. So instead of passing the className as prop, you can pass the `modalState` to Modal

```
Modal visible={modalState} />
<div className={visible ? styles.visible : styles.invisible}>
```

If you have more than one classes which depend upon a condition, I would recommend using [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not adding the className for me and when I inspect the element there is no class there whatsoever.